# Entity was of unexpected kind

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore

[image: this give database present in firestore]

1)Firstly i did firestore export through console

2) Secondly when i try load data from Cloud Firestore exports

```
 By steps given in this link - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore
```

3) I get the error saying  'Entity was of unexpected **** '

```
 Here '****' represents collection name in firestore
```

[image: this is error i get in bigquery during load]

Comment: Please share some code examples of what you have tried and any error messages you have received?

Comment: @ Ben P, updated with images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#limitations) when loading Firestore exports to BigQuery, these two may be related to the error you are observing:

- For a Cloud Firestore export to load correctly, documents in the export data must share a consistent schema.
- Your export command must specify a collection-ids filter. Data exported without specifying a collection ID filter cannot be loaded into BigQuery.

I also noticed you are following the procedure to load Datastore Exports to BigQuery. You may want to follow [Firestore Exports to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#loading_cloud_firestore_export_service_data) instead, although they are very similar.

Comment: This answer is really helpful. I followed instructions from a Firebase help article to schedule daily exports of my Firestore data. When I needed to access one of the backups, I followed the documentation to try loading it BigQuery but I kept hitting the same error. The error is because my backups are of all collections which means they cannot be loaded in BigQuery. Instead I had to import the export files back into Firestore using the Firestore Import/Export screen in the GCP console. Leaving this comment here in case it helps anyone else in the future who runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that exporting a single collection solved this exact issue for me.

For whatever reason, firestore refused to allow me to export a specific collection through the console UI, which made it impossible for me to get the data into bigquery. The workaround is to open the cloud shell terminal while on the firestore gcp console page and inserting the following command

```
$ gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME] --collection-ids=[COLLECTION_ID_1],[COLLECTION_ID_2]
```

More detail on this can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#gcloud_1